# Importing Gmail text to a specific Google Sheets

Tags: spreadsheet

I receive everyday the same email from an app I've made. Those emails have the same text except for some numbers (for example `2` instead of `9`). I'm trying to build a script that automatically compiles my Google Sheets report.

```
function myFunction() {
 var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("").getThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox
 var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
 Logger.log(message.getBody()); // log contents of the body
}
```

but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following script works for me. Note that due to the time it takes to execute and to stop duplicate results, I change the label after it is moved to the spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.openById("Insert Sheet ID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Import");

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label");
  var labelNew = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label Moved");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var sub = messages[j].getBody();

      sheet.appendRow([sub])
    }
       threads[i].addLabel(labelNew);
       threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```